# How to save state of webview in fragment while detaching?

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, android-webview

I have one fragment which contain webview. I am making multiple instance of that fragment.

So every time, I just detach the fragment instance and only attach that fragment instance which is needed.

The problem is when I detach the fragment Instance and reattach it. It just lost its state like if Youtube is open in one instance of fragment before detaching. After reattaching it ,it just show me home page(App home page not Youtube Home page).

I try to use show and hide method but it also causing the different problem.

Fragment add method

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment, new BlankFragment0(), fragemnt tag);// fragment tag is different for every instance
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Than I just detach and attach fragment instance according to my need.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries I figure out the thing

Now onPause method I save the view of the fragment.

```
public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        view = getView();
    }
```

and onCreate method I check either view is empty or not?

```
if(view!=null)
        {
            return view;
        }
        else {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank0, container, false);
        }
```